# Как отсортировать данный массив?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется следующий код

```
    var bool = [false, false, false];

var names = ["Банан", "Яблоко", "Груша"];
var prices = [10, 20, 30]


var text;

a = names.indexOf(text) >= 0;
b = !names.indexOf(text) >= 0;


function checkbuy (names) {
while (text != 0)
{
  text = prompt("cписок продуктов: " + names)
names.sort(function(){ })  **//ВОТ ЭТА СТРОКА!**  

  if (names.indexOf(text) >= 0)
  {
    bool[names.indexOf(text)] = true;
    alert("Продукт " + text.toUpperCase() + " куплен!");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
  {
    var myList = [ [names[i], prices[i], bool[i]], [names[i], prices[i], bool[i]], [names[i], prices[i], bool[i]] ];

    // alert(myList[i][0]);
    alert(names[i])

  }
  alert(names);
}
```

}

Хочу отсортировать массив таким образом, чтобы сначала шли значения, выведенные в prompt, и совпадающие с элементами массива, а потом лишь те, которые в prompt не выведены. Как реализовать подобную сортировку массива? Ломаю голову, не могу придумать.

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: у вас сортировка начинается раньше, чем `prompt`

Comment: @ThisMan Исправил. Но как саму сортировку написать, чтобы она вернула сначала значение из prompt, совпадающее с элементом массива, а потом все остальное?

Comment: а в каком формате вводятся значения в промт?

Comment: Ну то есть порядок сортировки должен быть такой: сначала идет то, что выведено в prompt и совпадает с элементом массива, потом все остальные элементы. Например, "Яблоко" введено в prompt, значит оно идет первым элементом, потом остальные, которые в prompt не выводились.

Comment: @ThisMan Формате? Ввожу текст типа string, если он совпадает (indexOf) с элементом массива (продукт), то элемент отмечается как "купленный", и нужно чтобы "купленные" шли первыми, потом будут идти не купленные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут правда есть жесткий формат того, что должно быть в `prompt`. Не учитываются значения, которых нет в `names` + лишние символы будут только мешать. Но это уже дело калибровки и форматирования

```js
const names = ["Банан", "Яблоко", "Груша", "Вишня", ];
const userInput = prompt('список товаров:', names);
const userNames = userInput.split(',');

console.log(names.sort((a, b) => {
  // Немного js магии, Number(true) === 1, Number(0) === 0
  // Функция sort должна возвращать число, в зависимости от того
  // какой элемент должен идти первым.
  return Number(userNames.includes(b)) - Number(userNames.includes(a));
}));
```

[Подробнее про `sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

**UPD**
Чуть более оптимизированный вариант без сортировки

```js
const names = ["Банан", "Яблоко", "Груша", "Вишня", ];
const userInput = prompt('список товаров:', names);
const userNames = userInput.split(',');

const result = {included: [], excluded: []};
names.forEach(name => {
  userNames.includes(name) ?
    result.included.push(name) :
    result.excluded.push(name);
});

console.log(...result.included, ...result.excluded);
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо! Ну, а насчет значений, которых нет в массиве, и лишних символов - не критично, я знаю как это исправить. Тему можно закрывать. :)

Comment: `Number` тут лишний. Вычитание и так число вернёт.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну по сути да, арифметическая операция сама приведет значения к числу, но как бы, так чуточку яснее

Comment: А вообще, если требовалось сделать именно то, что тут написано, то использование сортировки довольно неэффективно.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно и циклом пройтись, будет тогда линейное время выполнения

Comment: @ThisMan, из-за includes будет не линейное, а квадратичное. А с сортировкой и includes одновременно было бы `O(n**2 * lb(n))`. А вообще, я ожидал что надо отсортировать сначала про присутствию в списке, а потом по алфавиту. Но если внимательно прочитать вопрос, то там такого не написано)))

Comment: @Qwertiy да, про время я ошибся, забыл про `includes`